# How can I convert .vp file into .xml or .apk file?

Tags: android, html, xml, android-layout, justinmind

I'm using justinMind and I get .vp file.I am able to convert it in .html file but how can I convert it in .xml or .apk?I have tried to convert .html to .xml by using .tidy but It doesn't give me proper layout in my androidstudio.

Comment: You can open or display converted .html file in **wabView**

Comment: If this is what you ask https://www.justinmind.com/community/topic/can-justmind-export-the-prototype-directly-to-the-android-studio-project

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this SDK, but from I quick search, I found this post on there forum :

https://www.justinmind.com/community/topic/can-justmind-export-the-prototype-directly-to-the-android-studio-project

For long term save, here is the two post :

> Question : I can use the software for simple designing and prototyping. It will reduce the app build time if there is a way to export the files as an android studio project. Is this possible?

Answer

> Hi there,
>
> Unfortunately that is not possible. However, you can utilize the
>   generated CSS and Javascript, which may help reduce app build time.
>
> Best,
>
> Danielle

So you need to use the generetad HTML/Javascript/Css files with a WebView. So no, you can't create a project, only the HTML files.

Comment: I have HTML/JS and CSS files in my project, But how can I convert HTML to XML cause HTML doesn't give me proper layout in my app.

Comment: @DrashtiPandya The XML to create an Android Layout ? Doubt you can, like I said `I don't know this SDK` but this seems to be a prototyping software, not a full development kit